# the pages references are mixed

Tags: numbering, page, acrobat

There are three numbers in the AR. Call them [n], [nn] and [nnn].
In my snippet [n]=v, [nn]=5 and [nnn]=29.
The total number of pages is [nnn] so it is 29 in my example.
Now comes the problem: I have some stuff in the appendix.
**But** first two references (clickable links with the name of the
appropriate appendix position) direct me to [n] and the others to [nn].

Where is the **bug**, how can I make all clickable parts refer to [nn]  ?
So e.g. "A Some observations around the year 2000" directs me to [n]=3 and not to [nn]=11.
Strangely enough, the other two work fine.

[image]

Comment: the bug is in your code, your anchor names are not unique. You should get warnings in the log.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer What are `anchor names` and where can I change/find them ?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Is it necessary to use this: `\phantomsection\label{here}THE DESTINATION LINE (anchor x)` for anchor to work ?

Comment: no, you need to redefine a \theHxxxx command, but which one it is not possible to say without seeing the code. Or use the `hypertexnames=false` option, but then you can't use \autoref.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It works fine. Could you say in one or two sentences what is `\autoref` good for ? Google gives to me messy and long results. Perhaps you are an expert on this.

Comment: autoref is described in the hyperref documentation, if you don't use it, you don't need to care about it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I would potentially use it if I knew the purpose. Even for curiosity I would like to know what's this `autoref`.